# $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\cong (\operatorname{Spec}(A(Y)),\mathcal{O}_{A(Y)}) $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Given an affine variety, which is defined to the vanishing set $V(I)$ over an algebraic field $k$. We know its coordinate ring $A(Y)$ has the property that $\mathcal{O}(Y)\cong A(Y)$. I wonder if we have that $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\cong (\operatorname{Spec}(A(Y)),\mathcal{O}_{A(Y)}) $ so that $Y$ is an affine scheme?

Comment: If you mean that $V(I)\subset \Bbb k^n$, the answer is no for positive-dimensional $Y$ because then $Y$ does not contain generic points, while $\operatorname{Spec}(A(Y))$ does. Instead, what is true is that there is a unique functor which turns these things in to affine schemes and this functor is fully faithful. Details should be somewhere in the beginning of chapter 2 of Hartshorne.

Comment: @KReiser is that why you claim variety is a scheme?

Comment: While a variety (whatever your actual definition of that is) may not literally be a scheme, anything you could reasonably call a variety should be viewable as a scheme under some sort of fully faithful "schemeifcation" functor. The word "variety" can have lots of different meanings depending on who's writing it - for example, when I write variety, I usually mean separated scheme of finite type over a field. Others will add reduced, integral, etc or view it as a subset of $k^n$. So it's important to be careful if the definition matters like it does in this question.